# failed linking references - android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting the following error in my android studio project build

> failed linking references,
>   error: resource id/edit_query (aka package:id/edit_query) not found.Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource id/edit_query (aka
>   package:id/edit_query) not found.,
>   sources=[C:\gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\3482cd36ff1fc3489bd4ff1aeced93ab\res\values\values.xml:2689:5-2691:13],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

**my project build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**my module build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.weprcl.lathikashetty.weparcel"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.11'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I tried every answer in the same issue questions but without benefit so any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

**